# To clip a QPainterPath by QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, graph, qgraphicsitem

In the the screenshot below all nodes are derived from QGraphicsItem and all edges are drawn by an instance of QPainterPath.

(Colored for clarity)
[image]

Is it possible to have the nodes clip/obscure the edges? Ideally, I'd like to have the edge invisible as soon as it "enters" a node. Is this possible with QPainterPath or do I have to use another way to draw paths?

Comment: Can you just fill the node painter path with white and paint them after the edges? That would be a pretty simple solution if it would work in your situation.

Comment: @DaveMateer Well, its somewhat complicated. My "drawing algorithm" first draws a node and then all its ingoing edges. Is it somehow possible to get the intersection point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [GraphicsLineItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicslineitem.html) instead of [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpainterpath.html) then you have access to [setZValue](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsitem.html#setZValue) to do this.

I don't immediately see a way to do this with [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpainterpath.html).

Comment: -1 This wouldn't solve the problem at all.  Each node would be be made of 4 individual scene items (one for each edge), making them impossible to fill, and dramatically increasing the amount of boiler plate to write.  `QGraphicsPolygonItem` would make far more sense, but even then, unless the node will be filled with a colour (as noted by Dave Mateer), the joining lines would still be visible.

Comment: The nodes are already derived from QGraphicsItem. The quick hack is to use QGraphicsLineItem after filling in the background on their node class.  Better option is probably to check out the diagram example from the docs. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-diagramscene.html